# Index is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function where I am populating a 100x100 2D array with values by iterating over a for loop. I need to store values in the [i][i], [i][i-1], and [i][i+1] positions.Here is what i have so far:

```
    Delta = 1/100
    N = 100 
    Matrix = np.zeros(N,N), int)

    for i in range(N):
       Matrix[i][i] = ((2*D)/pow(Delta,2) + SigmaA)
       Matrix[i][i-1] = -(D/pow(Delta,2))
       Matrix[i][i+1] = -(D/pow(Delta,2))
```

Comment: `Matrix[i][i+1]` is the problem.  `N` is 100  so `i` will go from 0 to 99.  When `i` is 99.  `i+1` is 100 which is out of bounds.  (Your valid indexes for each dimension go from 0 to 99.)

Comment: What @StevenRumbalski said.  If you're going to do a range like that and append something to the -1 and +1 (which I'm surprised that 0 hasn't thrown an error), you need to go the range (1, 99)

Comment: What happens to `i+1` when `i` is the maximum value in the array, `100`?

Comment: @CBredlow 0 doesn't throw an error because 0-1=-1 which refers to the last element of the array. In this case that does not lead to any problems because that index will be overwritten later anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i+1` and `i-1` are both trying to access an invalid index. Make your matrix `1` bigger than needed, and have `range` start at 1 and go to N+1.

```
Delta = 1/100
N = 100 
Matrix = np.zeros(N+1,N+1), int)

for i in range(1,N+1):
   Matrix[i][i] = ((2*D)/pow(Delta,2) + SigmaA)
   Matrix[i][i-1] = -(D/pow(Delta,2))
   Matrix[i][i+1] = -(D/pow(Delta,2))
```

Comment: Your indices range from 0 to N (not 1, N+1).

Comment: @Joooeey Thank you

Comment: This returns Matrix[i][i+1] = -(D/pow(Delta,2))
IndexError: index 101 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 101

Comment: For indices ronge from 0 to N as suggested by @Joooeey the top right element is not 0 as it should be.